# Chinese Remainder Theorem, remainder when dividing by a polynomial

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I was reading throught this question: [Give the remainder of $x^{100}$ divided by $(x-2)(x-1)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772326/give-the-remainder-of-x100-divided-by-x-2x-1) and I couldn't get the same expression as the answers.

I have a basic understanding of modulos and Chinese Remainder Theorem so here is what I tried:

1) `x^100 ≡ p mod (x-1)`

2) `x^100 ≡ r mod (x-2)`

since (x-1) and (x-2) are relatively prime.

EQ. 1 gives `x^100 = p + a(x-1)`

```
x^100 ≡ p + a(x-1) ≡ r mod (x-2)

x^100 ≡ p - r + a(x-1) mod (x-2)

x^100 = p - r + a(x-1) + b(x-2)

x^100 = p-r + ax - a + bx - 2b
```

Let R = p - r - a - 2b

```
x^100 = x(a+b) - R
```

Is this correct? If this is correct how are the answers derived in that question? If not, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it can be done by (Lagrange) interpolation, it is just as simple (and more powerful) to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT), which is $\color{#c00}{\rm very\ easy}$ when the $\color{#c00}{\rm Bezout}$ identity is known

By CRT, $ $ if $\ \color{#c00}{j g} + \color{#c00}{k h} = 1\,$ then $\ \begin{eqnarray}f\equiv a\!\!\!\pmod g\\f\equiv b\!\!\!\pmod h\end{eqnarray}$ $\!\iff\!\!$ $\begin{eqnarray} f&\equiv&\  a\,\color{#c00}{kh}\, +\, b\,\color{#c00}{jg}&&({\rm mod}\ {gh})\\  &\equiv& a+(b\!-\!a)\color{#c00}{jg}&&({\rm mod}\ gh)\end{eqnarray}$

So $\, \underbrace{(x\!-\!1)}_{\large g}-\underbrace{(x\!-\!2)}_{\large h} = 1,$ $\, a,b = f(1),f(2) \Rightarrow f\equiv f(1) +(f(2)\!-\!f(1))(x\!-\!1) \pmod{\!\!(x\!-\!1)(x\!-\!2)}$

**Remark** $\ $ It was $\,\color{#c00}{\rm easy}$ here since $\,\ g\ {\rm mod}\ h = g - h = (x\!-\!1)-(x\!-\!2) = 1\ $ is invertible in $\,\Bbb Q\,$ hence this immediately yields the Bezout identity, which immediately yields the solution as above. Generally it is just as easy when $\ g\ {\rm mod}\ h\ $ is invertible (which is equivalent to the extended Euclidean algorithm (EEA) terminating in $1$ step, i.e. this is an *optimization* of the EEA). In particular, the EEA terminates in one step if one of the polynomials is *linear*.

Since Lagrange interpolation is the special case of CRT when both moduli are *linear* polynomials, the above optimization always applies.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3177321/242) for a convenient general approach using this method of transforming the Bezout GCD identity.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^{100} = P(x)(x-1)(x-2) + ax + b$$

for some polynomial $P(x)$ and some integers $a$ and $b$.

\begin{align}
   x=1 
   &\implies 1 = P(1)\cdot 0 + a+b \\
   &\implies a+b = 1 \\
   x=2
   &\implies 2^{100} = P(2)\cdot 0 + 2a+b \\
   &\implies 2a + b = 2^{100} \\
   &\implies x^{100} = P(x)(x-1)(x-2) + (2^{100}-1)x - (2^{100}-2)
\end{align}

Comment: Ha! Way to revive such an old question. And now that I look at it...this answer seems so much simpler.